# Trying to wrap a reduce function in another function so as to make it more general

Tags: javascript, callback, reduce

My object looks like this:

```
 electionResults = {
  constituency_1:{
    party1:'200',
    party2:'400'
    ...
  },
  constituency_2:{
    party1:'100',
    party2:'500'
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

and I'm tallying results like this:

```
Object.values(electionResults).reduce((t, {party1}) => t + +party1, 0)
```

I'd like to be able to wrap it like this:

```
function partyTally(myParty){
   return Object.values(electionResults).reduce((t, myParty) => t + +party1, 0)
}
```

but can't figure out how to pass `myParty` through to the reduce callback function.
I created the object myself from a tsv file, so can reconfigure it readily if needed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

required function should read:

```
function partyTally(myParty){
   return Object.values(electionResults).reduce((t, myParty) => t + +**myParty**, 0)
}
```

Comment: I don't get what is `myParty` in your code. Can you explain more?

Comment: So these are election results, and myParty is any political party eg party1

Comment: I still don't get it. Maybe you wanna do something like "pass a party, then count all party1 in electionResults", if so, just use `Array.prototype.find` to find the needed party and then pass that `party` into reduce function. But tbh, don't get why you need to do so.

Comment: both jasweski and IamOren have anserwered this fine.  IamOren spotted the typo, hence the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

party1 was the problem.  Here:

```
function partyTally(myParty){
  return Object.values(electionResults).reduce((t, c) => t + Number(c[myParty]), 0)
}
```

Pass "party1", for example.

Here is a way to tally all parties from all constituencies at once:

```js
electionResults = {
  "constituency_1": {
    "party1": "200",
    "party2": "400"
  },
  "constituency_2": {
    "party1": "100",
    "party2": "500"
  }
};

partiesTally = Object.values(electionResults).reduce((result, constituency) => {
  Object.keys(constituency).forEach(party => {
    if(result[party]==undefined) result[party]=0;
    result[party]+=(+constituency[party]);
  });
  return result;
},{});

console.log(partiesTally);
```

Comment: So, you like? :)  If so, please select and up-vote my answer - thanks!

Comment: Hi iAmOren - I can't up-vote publicly as my reputation is too low.  Otherwise I would. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks.  Accept?

Comment: @NumberJay, see my addition.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using the full argument from `Object.values` rather than trying to destructure immediately within the callback.

```
function partyTally(myParty){
  return Object.values(electionResults).reduce((t, constituencyResults) => t + +constituencyResults[myParty], 0)
}
```